# Сортировка разных частей списка по возрастанию и по убыванию

Tags: python

Как сортировать список по 10 элементов (первый десяток по возрастанию, второй по убыванию)?

Пытался сделать так, но он берет каждые 10 элементов, а я не могу понять как сделать каждые 10 через 10:

```
list_1 = [randint(1, 1000) for i in range(40)]

for i in range(0, len(list_1), 10):
    print(sorted(list_1[i: i+10]))
    print(sorted(list_1[i: i+10], reverse=True))
```

Comment: Идете циклом for по индексам `range(0, len(список), 10)`, делаете `список[i: i+10] = sorted(список[i: i+10])` (если по возрастанию) или `список[i: i+10] = sorted(список[i: i+10], reverse=True)` (если нужно по убыванию). Как определить четную/нечетную десятку - это уже вам на подумать.

Comment: судя по всему, в этом и заключается задача - как чередовать сортировку. Если тебе дадут готовое решение, тебе это не принесет никакой пользы. А вот если сам придумаешь, то получишь а) опыт решения задач, б) вброс позитива потому что смог решить сложную задачу.

Comment: Нужно проверять, если десятка "четная" (i // 10 % 2 == 0), то сортировать по возрастанию (первая десятка получится нулевой), иначе по убыванию. "Проверять" - значит нужен if.

Comment: @insolor можно и без проверки. Просто заменить в приведенном коде пару значений.

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, куча вариантов решения

Comment: Я бы вообще в `enumerate` обернул и через его значение чёт-нечёт определял )

Comment: А я бы вообще триггер сделал, причем его значения - True и False -  использовал в качестве значения параметра reverse. Так что вариантов столько, сколько программистов :-)

Answer (score 0):

Несколько вариантов:

1. Идете циклом for по индексам с шагом 10, проверяете четная это десятка или нечетная, сортируете, записываете на исходное место:

```
from random import randint

list_1 = [randint(1, 1000) for i in range(40)]

for i in range(0, len(list_1), 10):
    if i // 10 % 2 == 0:
        list_1[i: i+10] = sorted(list_1[i: i+10])
    else:
        list_1[i: i+10] = sorted(list_1[i: i+10], reverse=True)

print(list_1)
```

2. То же самое, только вместо if подставляете проверку четности/нечетности десятки в параметр reverse:

```
from random import randint

list_1 = [randint(1, 1000) for i in range(40)]

for i in range(0, len(list_1), 10):
    list_1[i: i+10] = sorted(list_1[i: i+10], reverse=(i // 10 % 2 != 0))

print(list_1)
```

3. Идете циклом не с шагом 10, а с шагом 20, внутри каждой двадцатки первую десятку сортируете по возрастанию, вторую - по убыванию:

```
from random import randint

list_1 = [randint(1, 1000) for i in range(40)]

for i in range(0, len(list_1), 20):
    list_1[i: i+10] = sorted(list_1[i: i+10])
    list_1[i+10: i+20] = sorted(list_1[i+10: i+20], reverse=True)

print(list_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from random import randint

c11 = [randint(1, 1000) for i in range(40)]

step = 10
for i in range(0, len(c11), step):
    s = slice(i, i + step)
    c11[s] = sorted(c11[s], reverse=i % (step * 2))
```