# Собрать все данные в одну строку[Python]

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
У меня есть условие:

```
if i // 10 % 2 == 0:
    print(sorted(list_1[i: i+10]))
else:
    print(sorted(list_1[i: i + 10], reverse=True))
```

Не могу сообразить чтоб оно выводились в один список.
Пытался сделать так, но оно выводит лишь половину:

```
el = list_1
el_2 = list_1
for i in range(0, len(list_1), 10):
    if i // 10 % 2 == 0:
        el = sorted(list_1[i: i+10])
    else:
        el_2 = sorted(list_1[i: i + 10], reverse=True)
print(el + el_2)
```

Comment: "Не могу сообразить чтоб" - сообразите прочитать синтаксис `print`:-) Как обнаружите там `end =`, так  приравняйте его к пробелу (он автоматически заменит перевод строки). И в будущем так поступайте (начаинайте с изучения синтаксиса).

Comment: Это вывод в одну строку... А мне нужно вывести в один список!

Comment: @Максим если внимательно прочитать [мой комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1439500/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0python#comment2568878_1439500), то можно увидеть там пример, как записать отсортированный кусок на то же самое место.